# How to call CFileDialog class constructor

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, constructor, mfc, cfiledialog

I need a CFileDialog object to be used in all of the member functions of a class. So I wrote the header of class as:

```
#pragma once
#include <string.h>
#include "afxdlgs.h"
#include "gdal_priv.h"
#include "cpl_conv.h"
#include "cpl_string.h"
#include "ogr_spatialref.h"


class FilesWorkFlow
{
public:
    FilesWorkFlow(void);
    virtual ~FilesWorkFlow(void);
    CString GetPath();
    GDALDataset* OpenTiff(CString);
private:
    wchar_t* lpszFilter;
    CFileDialog dlgFile;
};
```

and implemented the constructor of the class in this form:

```
FilesWorkFlow::FilesWorkFlow(void)
{
    lpszFilter = _T("JPEG Files (*.jpg)|*.jpg|")
    _T("TIFF Files (*.tif)|*.tif|")_T("PNG Files (*.png)|*.png|")_T("Bitmap Files (*.bmp)|*.bmp|");

    dlgFile = CFileDialog(true,0,0,OFN_ENABLESIZING | OFN_HIDEREADONLY,lpszFilter,0,0,true);
}
```

but in the constructor, I get the error:

```
no default constructor exists for class CFileDialog
```

what is the problem?

### -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Problem solved. I implemented the class this way.

**FilesWorkFlow.h**

```
class FilesWorkFlow
{
public:
    FilesWorkFlow(void);
    virtual ~FilesWorkFlow(void);
    CString GetPath();
    GDALDataset* OpenTiff(CString);
private:
    wchar_t* lpszFilter;
    CFileDialog* dlgFile;
};
```

**FilesWorkFlow.cpp**

```
FilesWorkFlow::FilesWorkFlow(void)
{
        lpszFilter = _T("JPEG Files (*.jpg)|*.jpg|")
    _T("TIFF Files (*.tif)|*.tif|")_T("PNG Files (*.png)|*.png|")_T("Bitmap Files (*.bmp)|*.bmp|");
        dlgFile = new CFileDialog(true,0,0,OFN_ENABLESIZING | OFN_HIDEREADONLY,lpszFilter,0,0,true);
}


FilesWorkFlow::~FilesWorkFlow(void)
{
}


CString FilesWorkFlow::GetPath()
{
    if (dlgFile->DoModal() == IDOK)
    {
        CString pathname = dlgFile->GetPathName();
        return pathname;
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To specialize the `CFileDialog` you usually derive from it, instead of making it a class member. Regardless of what you do, though, the solution is to initialize the `CFileDialog` object through an initializer list. Your constructor would look like this:

```
FilesWorkFlow::FilesWorkFlow(void) :
    dlgFile( true, 0, 0,
             OFN_ENABLESIENABLESIZING | OFN_HIDEREADONLY,
             _T("JPEG Files (*.jpg)|*.jpg|TIFF Files (*.tif)|*.tif|PNG Files (*.png)|*.png|Bitmap Files (*.bmp)|*.bmp||"),
             0, 0, true )
{
}
```

Comment: thanks @Tim but this way `dlgFile` will only be known in the constructor and not in other function members as I told about Michael's answer. By the way what do you mean `To specialize the CFileDialog you usually derive from it, instead of making it a class member`? Could you explain a little more?

Comment: @sepideh The code above assumes that `dlgFile` is a class member as declared in your initial class definition. As such it is accessible to all member functions. `CFileDialog` is usually either used as is, or if you want to modify its behavior, i.e. specialize it for your use case, derived from. Your derived class can access all public and protected members of `CFileDialog`. This allows you to implement, for example, custom handling of type changes by overriding `OnTypeChange`.

Comment: thanks @Tim it was the best possible solution. I won't lose class `CFileDialog` capabilities and also I will have my own functions to enhance the abilities.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
FilesWorkFlow::FilesWorkFlow(void)
{
    lpszFilter = _T("JPEG Files (*.jpg)|*.jpg|")
    _T("TIFF Files (*.tif)|*.tif|")_T("PNG Files (*.png)|*.png|")_T("Bitmap Files (*.bmp)|*.bmp|");

    CFileDialog *dlgFile = new CFileDialog(true,0,0,OFN_ENABLESIZING | OFN_HIDEREADONLY,lpszFilter,0,0,true);
    ...
    delete dlgfile ;
}
```

or

```
FilesWorkFlow::FilesWorkFlow(void)
{
    lpszFilter = _T("JPEG Files (*.jpg)|*.jpg|")
    _T("TIFF Files (*.tif)|*.tif|")_T("PNG Files (*.png)|*.png|")_T("Bitmap Files (*.bmp)|*.bmp|");

    CFileDialog dlgFile(true,0,0,OFN_ENABLESIZING | OFN_HIDEREADONLY,lpszFilter,0,0,true);
    ...
}
```

Comment: thanks @Michael Waltz but this way `dlgFile` will be a local variable to the constructor and will not be available in other functions of the class. I need `dlgFile` to be member data of the class.

Comment: Your implementation seems correct, but eventually you havt to call "delete dlgFile ;" possibly in the destructor of the FilesWorkFlow class. Please accept my answer. Thx.

Comment: thanks @Michael Walz but what will be the risk if I call `delete dlgFile` in the destructor of the class?

Comment: No risk normally. But if you omit the `delete` you will have a memory leak. For each `X = new ...` you must have a `delete X ;` somewhere.